# Not able to create a new session using appium-android, however I am giving the right package name

Tags: java, android, package, appium

I am trying to automate an app using appium on android platform.
---Consider the app is like watsapp. after downloading the app user has to 
      configure it and he would be able to use it.
1)  I am able to launch the app but its not showing the option to continue using android inspector.
2) I want to start my app from where we give the pass code and it lands to the chat page in watsapp.

```
public class TestAndroidchatAPP {

    static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            chatAPP();
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public static void chatAPP() throws IOException {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "samsungGalaxyS5");
        caps.setCapability("uuid", "446bc30b");
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.chatAPP.chatapp");
        //caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.chatAPP.chatapp.LauncherActivity"); //its working.
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.chatAPP.chatapp.view.LoginPicodeActivity");

        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url, caps);
        System.out.println("Application started");
    }
}
```

> Below error is show in logcat

```
Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.chatAPP.chatapp' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.chatAPP.chatapp' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Activity name '.com.chatAPP.chatapp.view.LoginPicodeActivity' used to start the app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

    Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
    remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.chatAPP.chatapp' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.chatAPP.chatapp' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Activity name '.com.chatAPP.chatapp.view.LoginPicodeActivity' used to start the app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity
        at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:826:9)
        at asyncHandler (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:447:37)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this log : `Activity name '.com.chatAPP.chatapp.view.LoginPicodeActivity' used to start the app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity`

`LoginPicodeActivity` is not a launchable activity, you have to add attribute LAUNCHER inside AndroidManifest.xml inside the application code base.

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

You can see explanation about manifest [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro#example).

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to provide correct [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity) class name, you can determine it like:

   - launch the application you're trying to test on the device
   - execute the following [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) command

     ```
     adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'
     ```

   if the application not installed use [`app` desired capability instead](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/remote/MobileCapabilityType.html#APP) and provide full path or URL to the .apk file.
2. Given you're automating Android 6.0.1 device consider setting[`automationName` desired capability](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Capabilities):

   ```
   caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
   ```

   otherwise you will not be able to locate elements and your test might be flaky, you should be using [uiautomator2](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/android-uiautomator2/) for Android >= 5.0

Answer (score 0):

I did , its working fine when I added below 2 lines of code.

```
caps.setCapability("noReset", true);
caps.setCapability("fullReset", false);
```